# Is there a special name for the orthogonal projection matrix onto the unit vector?

Tags: matrices, terminology, projection

Many problems in multivariate analysis involve the $n \times n$ matrix:

$$\mathbf{M} \equiv \boldsymbol{I}_n - \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}_{n \times n}.$$

This is an [orthogonal projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Examples) onto the unit vector, so when it is applied to a column vector containing values $Y_1,...,Y_n$, this matrix subtracts the sample mean $\bar{Y}_n$ from these values:

$$\mathbf{Y} = \begin{bmatrix} Y_1 \\ \vdots \\ Y_n \end{bmatrix}
\quad \quad \quad \implies \quad \quad \quad 
\mathbf{M} \mathbf{Y} = \begin{bmatrix} Y_1 - \bar{Y}_n \\ \vdots \\ Y_n - \bar{Y}_n \end{bmatrix}.$$

There are many simple properties of this matrix, owing to the fact that it is an orthogonal projection matrix.  It has $\text{tr}(\mathbf{M}) = \text{rank}(\mathbf{M}) = n-1$, which means that it has a single zero eigenvalue and the remaining eigenvalues are all ones.  It comes up a lot in multivariate analysis, including statistical problems, where it is common to look at random vectors after subtracting their sample means.

**My question:** Does this matrix have any special name?  Is there a literature on this type of matrix?  Aside from the properties I have listed here, are there any other important properties of this matrix that are useful in statistical problems dealing with random vectors?

Comment: Maybe look at MDS or PCA literature. I vaguely recall it being called the mean-centering matrix there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment by [obscurans](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/619038/obscurans) I have now found out that this is called the [centering matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix).  It appears to be discussed specifically in some matrix textbooks, such as in [Zhang (2017)](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=YBs0DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) (pp. 111-112).  It does not appear to have any other important properties beyond what was listed in the question.